# How to notify some users when an attribute change in Magento?

Tags: magento, notifications, observer-pattern

I need to notify on group of user when a product is edited and saved and one **given** attribute has been changed.

Let's say I've an attribute `is_new` sets to false, if an admin update the product, I need to hook that this attribute has been changed and notify via emails the group "subscribers".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with events, there's some basic information on how to create events in the magento wiki:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

The event you need is probably catalog_product_save_before or catalog_product_save_after, depending on how you setup the code.